# Find interaction variables among large number of variables

Tags: regression, feature-selection, interaction

I have a large data set, containing some 220000 rows and 550 variables. I need to find interaction terms in order to increase the explanatory power of my model. However, I do not know how to locate interaction terms with such a large number of variables.

Is there any practical, or preferably automated, procedure to handle this kind of selection? I am using R so an R package would be fantastic.

Comment: Because there are 301950 interaction terms, you put yourself in a situation with more variables than observations.  That suggests trying other model-building techniques.

Answer (score 1):

First, in any situation I can think of, my first step would be to get rid of a lot of the 550 variables.  Even without interactions, that's a very large number of IVs and models will be uninterpetable.

Tree models can be useful for looking for interactions, but they are often hard to represent as the usual regression models.  A nice combination is multivariate adaptive regression splines (MARS).